# Update mysql row or column data with current datetime?

Tags: mysql, database

Here is my table structure below, How can I update my Num_pages column data so that it will insert with newly updated DateTime, rather than the old one.

[image: table]

Comment: What query are you looking to do here, an update or an insert?

Comment: Set `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in column specification. Read [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen update query with new DateTime and timestamp.

Comment: Are you trying to update the `Date_Time_Acqure` to a current timestamp whenever `Num_pages` field is being edited?

Comment: @tcadidot0 yes exactly I am trying to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can alter your `Date_Time_Acqure` field as following:

```
ALTER TABLE mytablename
    CHANGE COLUMN `Date_Time_Acqured` `Date_Time_Acqured` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
```

The column then will update to current timestamp whenever there's any change on the row; means that if you change any value from column `title` and not just `Num_Pages`, it will also update the `Date_Time_Acqure` to a current time.